# Validating Funky Radio CSS buttons with jquery

Tags: jquery, css, validation

I am using the jquery validation plugin to validate my form.  I got it validating my inputs and selects no problem.  However, I am using some custom fancy radio buttons, from here: https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/funky-radio-buttons

Now, I added "required" to each radio button and specified "required" in the validate method.  And it appears to be blocking the submit when empty.  But I can't get it to display a custom error message near the radio buttons.  I see that the fancy radio buttons work by hiding the regular radio buttons.  I wonder if that has to do with the display of the error message.

HTML:

```
<div class="funkyradio">
    <div class="funkyradio-red red">
    <input type="radio" name="track" id="radio1" value="neutral" required />
    <label for="radio1">$5.50 for Neutral</label>
    </div>
    <div class="funkyradio-yellow yellow">
        <input type="radio" name="track" id="radio2" value="2-wheel" required />
        <label for="radio2">$16 for 2 Wheel Drive</label>
    </div>
    <div class="funkyradio-green green">
        <input type="radio" name="track" id="radio3" value="4-wheel" required />
        <label for="radio3">$26.50 for 4 Wheel Drive</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

jquery:

```
$("#form").validate({
    rules: {
        email: {
          required: true,
          email: true,
          track: true
        },
        referralID: {
            required: false,
            digits: true
        },
        phone: {
            require_from_group: [1, ".contact-group"]
        },
        email: {
          require_from_group: [1, ".contact-group"]
        }
    },
    messages: {
        phone: {
            require_from_group: "'Phone Number' or 'Email' is required"
        },
        email: {
            require_from_group: "'Phone Number' or 'Email' is required"
        },
        track: "Please select a neutral, 2 wheel drive, or 4 wheel drive."

    }
});
```

This is the CSS that worries me:

```
.funkyradio input[type="radio"]:empty,
.funkyradio input[type="checkbox"]:empty {
   display: none;
}
```

**UPDATE**
As requested, I am using this jquery plugin for validation: https://jqueryvalidation.org/

Comment: If you have "fancy" radio buttons and/or checkboxes using CSS, hiding the actual `<input>` element and styling the `<label>` is normally the way it's done, so the CSS ruleset posted is ok. Although I cannot say for certain how the validate plugin handles them if hidden. There are a gazillion validation jQuery plugins so it would behoove you to provide the link to which this particular plugin is located.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be tweaked as followed:

```
$("#form").validate({
    rules: {
        email: {
          required: true,
          email: true,
          require_from_group: [1, ".contact-group"]
        },
        referralID: {
            required: false,
            digits: true
        },
        phone: {
            require_from_group: [1, ".contact-group"]
        },
        track: {
            required: true,
            require_from_group: [1, ".contact-group"]
        }
    },
    messages: {
        phone: {
            require_from_group: "'Phone Number' or 'Email' is required"
        },
        email: {
            require_from_group: "'Phone Number' or 'Email' is required"
        },
        track: "Please select a neutral, 2 wheel drive, or 4 wheel drive."

    }
});
```

EDIT:

Change:

```
track: "Please select a neutral, 2 wheel drive, or 4 wheel drive."
```

To

```
track: {
        require_from_group: "Please select a neutral, 2 wheel drive, or 4 wheel drive."
    }
```

Comment: I added in the rule for track.  I switched the class from `.contact-group` to `.track` and then added in a class of `.track` to each of the radio inputs.  But I'm still not getting any message when I submit when empty.